# Pass value over Promise in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I have a Promise chain like this

```
firstly {
   Network.shared.getInfo()
}
.then { info in
   Network.shared.getUserDetail(info)
}
.then { detail in
   Network.shared.getAddOn(detail)
}
.done { addOn in
 //do stuff with addOn
}
.catch { error in 
}
```

and I need to have all values (info, detail and addOn) in the `.done` Promise block. Is there a way to extend visibility or pass values throught Promise ?

I can't use `when(fulfilled: [])` because each value depends from the previous one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could propagate the inputs from your previous promise to the next promises by wrapping the new value and the previous one(s) in a tuple.

```
firstly {
   Network.shared.getInfo()
}
.then { info in
   (info, Network.shared.getUserDetail(info))
}
.then { info, detail in
   (info, detail, Network.shared.getAddOn(detail))
}
.done { info, detail, addOn in
 //do stuff with addOn
}
.catch { error in 
}
```

Alternatively, you could change your methods to return tuples themselves or to return a type which wraps the input arg and the newly generated return value.

So for instance change `Network.shared.getUserDetail(info)` from returning just `UserDetail` to returning `(UserInfo, UserDetail)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create variables to assign your values to,
Ex:

```swift
var info: Info
var detail: Detail
var addOn: AddOn

firstly {
   Network.shared.getInfo()
}
.then { info in
   self.info = info
   Network.shared.getUserDetail(info)
}
.then { detail in
   self.detail = detail
   Network.shared.getAddOn(detail)
}
.done { addOn in
   self.addOn = addOn

   //do stuff with addOn
}
.catch { error in 
}
```

Comment: This won't actually work, since you need to give default values to all properties. So you'd need to make the properties `Optional`, but then you'd need to unwrap them in `done`.